# seek a better design suggestion for a trial-and-error mechanism in python?

Tags: python, functional-programming, calculus

See below data matrix get from sensors, just INT numbers, nothing specical.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
1   25  0   25  66  41  47  40  12  69  76  1
2   17  23  73  97  99  39  84  26  0   44  45
3   34  15  55  4   77  2   96  92  22  18  71
4   85  4   71  99  66  42  28  41  27  39  75
5   65  27  28  95  82  56  23  44  97  42  38
…                                           
10  95  13  4   10  50  78  4   52  51  86  20
11  71  12  32  9   2   41  41  23  31  70  
12  54  31  68  78  55  19  56  99  67  34  94
13  47  68  79  66  10  23  67  42  16  11  96
14  25  12  88  45  71  87  53  21  96  34  41
```

The horizontal A to K is the sensor name, and vertical is the data from sensor by the timer manner.

Now I want to analysis those data with trial-and-error methods, I defined some concepts to explain what I want:

**o  source**

source is all the raw data I get

**o  entry**

a entry is a set of all A to K sensor, take the vertical 1st row for example: the entry is

```
25  0   25  66  41  47  40  12  69  76  1
```

**o  rules**

a rule is a "suppose" function with assert value return, so far just "true" or "false". 
For example, I suppose the sensor A, E and F value will never be same in one enrty, if one entry with A=E=F, it will tigger violation and this rule function will return false.

**o  range:**

a range is function for selecting vertical entry, for example, the first 5 entries

Then, the basic idea is:

```
o   source + range = subsource(s)
o   subsource + rules = valiation(s)
```

The finally I want to get a list may looks like this:

```
rangeID ruleID violation
1   1   Y
2   1   N
3   1   Y
1   2   N
2   2   N
3   2   Y
1   3   N
2   3   Y
3   3   Y
```

But the problem is the rule and range I defined here will getting very complicated soon if you looks deeper, they have too much possible combinations, take  "A=E=F" for example, one can define "B=E=F"，"C=E=F"，"C>F" ......

So soon I need a rule/range generator which may accept those "core parameters" such as "A=E=F" as input parameter even using regex string later. That is too complicated just defeated me, leave alone I may need to persistence rules unique ID,  data storage problem, rules self nest combination problem ......

**So my questions are:**

1. Anyone knows if there's some module/soft fit for this kind of trial-and-error calculation or the rules defination I want?
2. Anyone can share me a better rules/range design I described?

Thanks for any hints.

Rgs,

KC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, I probably wouldn't even venture down the Numbpy path as I don't think given your description that it's really required. Here's a sample implementation of how I might go about solving the specific issue that you presented:

```
l = [\
        {'a':25, 'b':0, 'c':25, 'd':66, 'e':41, 'f':47, 'g':40, 'h':12, 'i':69, 'j':76, 'k':1},\
        {'a':25, 'b':0, 'c':25, 'd':66, 'e':41, 'f':47, 'g':40, 'h':12, 'i':69, 'j':76, 'k':1}\
]
r = ['a=g=i', 'a=b', 'a=c']
res = []

# test all given rules
for n in range(0, len(r)):
        # i'm assuming equality here - you'd have to change this to accept other operators if needed
        c = r[n].split('=')
        vals = []
        # build up a list of values given our current rule
        for e in c:
                vals.append(l[0][e])
        # using len(set(v)) gives us the number of distinct values
        res.append({'rangeID': 0, 'ruleID':n, 'violation':'Y' if len(set(vals)) == 1 else 'N'})

print res
```

**Output:**

`[{'violation': 'N', 'ruleID': 0, 'rangeID': 0}, {'violation': 'N', 'ruleID': 1, 'rangeID': 0}, {'violation': 'Y', 'ruleID': 2, 'rangeID': 0}]`

http://ideone.com/zbTZr

There are a few assumptions made here (such as equality being the only operator in use in your rules) and some functionality left out (such as parsing your input to the `list` of `dict`s I used, but I'm hopeful that you can figure that out on your own.

Of course, there *could* be a Numpy-based solution that's simpler than this that I'm just not thinking of at the moment (it's late and I'm going to bed now ;)), but hopefully this helps you out anyway.

**Edit:**

Woops, missed something else (forgot to add it in prior to posting) - I only test the first element in `l` (the given range).. You'd just want to stick that in another `for` loop rather than using that hard-coded `0` index.

Comment: Thanks, Demian Brecht, you've pointed a way for me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at Numpy matrix for data structures like matrix etc. It exposes a list of functions that work on matrix manipulation.

As for rule / range generator I am afraid you will have to build your own domain specific language to achieve that.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, Numpy may simplify the matrix manipulation, but the major problem is the rules/ range design, regarding the domain specific language, any sample can share with me?

Comment: Well Antlr allows you to create simple syntax based rules  http://www.antlr.org/ ... If you read first 4 chapters of Antlr Book  you would be able to create your rule engine that can work against a given martix with =, <, > being the operators. You can also look at http://pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns