# How to write small DSL parser with operator module in python

Tags: python, dsl, operation

See below matrix data:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   89  92  18  7   90  35  60
2   62  60  90  91  38  30  50
3   59  91  98  81  67  88  70
4   20  28  31  9   91  6   18
5   80  27  66  1   33  91  18
6   82  30  47  8   39  22  32
7   14  11  70  39  18  10  56
8   98  95  84  47  28  62  99
```

I need to define "rule" function can return "true" or "false" for below asserts string for each row data:

```
A=B and B=C
A>C
B>C
C>D and D<E or D>F
A+B<30
A+B<=30                # this may using "A+B<30 or A+B=30" as alternative
str(A) march regex"[2-5][0-2]" 
myfoo(A) > 100 
A in myfoo(B)
A not_in $listname
A in $listname
```

Take **"A=B and B=C"** for example: If I pass row 1 into this rule, I want the rule return false because it is not right in this case.

My questions are:

1. How can I define a DSL parser to translater those "rules string" into a workable lambda function, then I can invoke this lambda with data row as parameter to return the assert result?
2. I noticed the module operation has a lot of math functions I can reuse to define the rule, can I create a "mapper" for those keywords for DSL parser use?
   It may looks like:

   keywords = {"+": operation.add(),
               "/": operation.div(),
               "and": my_and_define()
              }
3. if above 2 are possible, how can I process the "A in $listname" in the lambda and in the mapper?

Thanks for your help.

Rgs,

KC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

```
class Rule( object ):
    def __init__( self, text ):
        self.text= text
    def test( self, A, B, C, D, E, F, G ):
        return eval( self.text )

r1= Rule( "A==B" )
r2= Rule( "A==B and B==C" )
r3= Rule( "A in {listname!s}".format( listname=someList ) )
```

etc.

```
>>> r1.test( 89,  92,  18,  7,   90,  35, 60 )
False
```

---

Edit.

- str(A) march regex"[2-5][0-2]"
- myfoo(A) > 100
- A is in myfoo(B)

These are all trivial Python code.  I'm not sure why the comment is even included as being interesting or difficult.

```
r4= Rule( "re.match( r'[2-5][0-2]', str(A) )" )
r5= Rule( "myfoo(A) > 100" )
r6= Rule( "A in myfoo(B)" )
```

There's a trick to this.  The trick is to write the Python code; and then enclose the code in quotes.  **Any** Python code is legal.

If the Python aspect of these rules is confusion, a Python tutorial may be helpful.

Comment: This fails if the rules aren't precisely Python expressions. OP's examples aren't.

Comment: @delnan: While true, I doubt that OP's DSL is already fixed by law or other standard.  I suspect there's a little room for maneuvering in the DSL that was specified.

Comment: @S.Lott, thanks for your sample, its quite clear and simple. while I still have questions for using the eval() instead of DSL, how to process below 3 rule strings: str(A) march regex"[2-5][0-2]", 
myfoo(A) > 100 , A is in myfoo(B)

Comment: @delnan, I think eval() also acceptable if it can solve all request I want, for after all, it is an internal DSL while to design an external DSL is quite complicated, but I doubt the eval() may not so extendable later

Comment: @user478514: Please **update** the question so that it is complete and has **all** the requirements.

Comment: @S.Lott, thanks for your help, question updated, I realized that the eval() can do almost eveything in my case if the rule string is legal python code.

Comment: @user478514: "eval() can do almost eveything".  False.  It can do everything.

Answer (score 1):

How important is the example syntax of your DSL? The simplest approach would be to use the Python expression syntax and eval(). Otherwise it might be possible to translate from your form to something eval()able.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I think to design an external DSL is a better idea, at least it would more extendable. This was inspired by answer on my last post, but to be frank I have no idea how to do it so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196767/seek-a-better-desing-suggestion-for-a-trial-and-error-mechanism-in-python

Comment: I am in considering to use the eval(), the problem is how to process the rule string in a single line? I means, the A B C D and the $listname?